# UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "D:\" is denied

Tags: exception, build, compiler-errors, console

I'm Oleg. Today I want to build a progect in Unity 2017.4.36f1 (64-bit) and then me in the Colsole appeared Error about UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "D:\" is denied. Please HELP me with that problem. More information you can see here.

UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "D:\" is denied. System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectoriesInternal (System.String path) (at :0) System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory (System.String path) (at :0) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.ZipIl2cppSymbols.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at :0) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at :0) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String stagingAreaData, System.String stagingArea, System.String playerPackage, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at :0) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args) (at :0) UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.BuildReporting.BuildReport report) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:272) UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (*"why isn't this code working?"*) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You should show us the code.